# How can I convert including timezone date in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I want to convert `2015-08-14T20:02:25-04:00` to `2015-08-14 16:02`
I tried below, but it could't execute well(returned nil).

```
let d = "2015-08-14T20:02:25-04:00"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"
let date: NSDate? = formatter.dateFromString(d)
```

How can I convert this date format?

Comment: I'm no sure if `NSDateFormatter` has a direct way, but you can decompose the string (ie. split into date, time, TZ) and build a conforming string to put into  `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**Xcode 8 • Swift 3**

You need to escape 'T' and use the appropriate timezone symbol. Note that it will depend if your date string represents a UTC (zero seconds from GMT) time timezone with Z `"XXXXX"` or without it +00:00 `"xxxxx"`:

```
let dateString = "2015-08-14T20:02:25-04:00"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX"
if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    let string = formatter.string(from: date)
    print(string)
}
```

If you need some reference you can use this:

[image]

Comment: @Vakas feel free to post a new question with your code and the steps necessary to reproduce the problem I will gladly take a look if you would like me to

Comment: @LeoDabus Let me try a bit, will post a question if not resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @Vakas I tested +05:00 and it gave me the time with 8 hours less which is the correct offset from where I am -03:00

Comment: @LeoDabus woking for me as well, I had some other issue in my date string.

Answer (score 10):

You can use :

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"
```

Hope this help you !

Comment: You the best!))