# How can I completely ignore time zones in entire app?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, timezone, nsdateformatter

I am having a miserable time with dates/times in one particular app. It's an event booking app, where I don't even want to know that there is such a thing as timezones. I want one time and only one time, regardless of where the user is currently located. I don't EVER want the time converted to any other locale/timezone. There is no such thing as "local" time in this app, as everything is based on the time for the location where you booked the event. It needs to always be expressed in that time, not the time where you currently are. As such, I don't really need any timezone features.

For example, you are in New York and you book an event/appointment in London for 10:30 pm on March 15. Now, regardless of whether you are in New York, London, or any other city in the world, that event is still at 10:30 pm on March 15 in London. If you're on vacation in Los Cabos, you DO NOT want to know that your event is at 3:30 pm Los Cabos time.

Before anyone explains to me that NSDate does not contain timezone data, I am completely aware of that, and that info is useless to me. An NSDate may have no timezone info, but the dates get converted thousands of times, and every conversion takes the timezone into account, causing me great misery. I have about 30 extensions on NSDate, trying to make sure it NEVER returns a local time (try to keep everything at UTC). Thought I had it beat, but apparently the DatePicker has it's own date formatter, so all of the date pickers now screw up.

There MUST be a way to deal with this in a relatively simple way. I tried dealing with everything as UTC dates, from the remote database to the web services to everything in the iOS app, making sure that everything converted to/from strings, etc. stays in UTC format. Still not having much luck. I can create an elaborate animation in minutes, but I've been fighting with these stupid dates for weeks.

What is the best way to approach this?

1. Everything in one time zone (e.g. UTC)
2. Force app local time zone to be same for everyone?
3. Store time in time zone of event location, then always try to display it based on that timezone? This sounds complicated but I'm afraid it's the direction I should take, even though it's overkill.
4. Create date formatter and reset locale every time I touch a date?
5. Other?

Comment: It looks like you just need time zones :-)

Comment: Your problem it is exactly what you are trying to do. Just forget about time zones. If you need to a date at a specific location you just have to pass that time zone to the date formatter when extracting the date from the string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32023076/2303865

Comment: So, what about things like date pickers? They automatically convert the time to your current time zone. No strings or manual conversion involved. I give it an NSDate and it always displays the wrong time (the time in MY time zone, not the timezone of the event).

Comment: I changed the locale in the date picker, but I still always get the local time.

Comment: I'm ok with the down vote, but could the person that down voted the question please explain the reasoning, so I can learn from my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: First comment above is wrong. I DO NOT need time zones. What do I need them for? I would simply use a text based date, if I didn't date search capability in the database. I never need to know or care about the time zone the user is in? When would I EVER need to know it? I NEVER want to display the date/time based on the zone they are currently in. NEVER.

Comment: Never say never. You will probably regret totally ignoring timezones. Or at least the next developer that has to update the code you started because there is a new need to deal with them.

Comment: Ya, you're right. I was jut having a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the thing. Ignore timezones except for two actions in your app:

1. When showing dates/times to a user.
2. When getting dates/times from a user.

Once you have an `NSDate`, forget timezones exist. Persist `NSDate` as-is. Do calculations with `NSDate` as-is. In a sense, this means everything is done in UTC time. It's all consistent. It's all uncomplicated.

You only worry about timezones when showing those dates to a user or when getting them from a user. That's it.

If you want the user's locale time, just use `NSDateFormatter` and its default timezone to show or get local times.

If you want to show or get times specific to an event, use an `NSDateFormatter` with its timezone set to the timezone of the event.

It's not any more complicated than this.

It always seems more complicated I think because people start logging `NSDate` and see what looks like the wrong time because they don't realize the output of the `NSLog` is in UTC time, not local time.

For example, you have a `UIDatePicker` for an event in London. Set the date picker's timezone to London time. Store the resulting `NSDate`. When you want to show the event's time to the user, set the timezone of the `NSDateFormatter` to London time. Then, no matter where the user is, it will show the proper London time.

Comment: Thanks. Good explanation.

Comment: So how do I actually implement this? Store the time zone in the database with each date, retrieve it back and pass the time zones around in the entity classes along with the dates? What format do most people store the time zones in? SecondsFromGMT as Int? Do I have to worry about daylight savings time changes? How do you store the dates on the database? In UTC, or in the time zone of the date (the time zone you're storing with it), or do you just handle it right in the date format using standard ISO format?

Comment: Just store all dates as-is (which is essentially GMT). The specifics depends on where/how you store the `NSDate`. Only worry about a timezone when you need to display the `NSDate` to the user.

Comment: That's the easy part. The storing and NSDates are not the problem. The problem areas are the "only worry about" parts. I have a calendar in local time, which contains hundreds of events, each of which could (in theory) be in a different time zone. Since I have to display every one of them at some point, to pull this off using the described method, for every date value, I need to: a) figure out the time zone for the event location b) pass the time zones via web service c) store the time zones in the mySQL database, retrieve the time zones back in the web services,

Comment: e) add the time zone to all classes that have dates, f) pass the time zones between screens, and finally, g) use the time zone passed around with each date to convert for display. I'm assuming this is how I have to do it. I've been storing the "time zone" as SecondsFromGMT, which seems to work better. I can't just worry about the time zone when I need to display the date, or else I won't know what the time zone IS when I need to display it. That's the part everyone leaves out of their explanation.

Comment: This ended up working very well for me. For each facility, I stored the "SecondsFromGMT", then used that value whenever displaying dates that would be associated with a facility. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's one problem with storage of "SecondsFromGMT" - these seconds may suddenly be different in a future date OR the date of event due to DST kicking in or turning off. Unless you store SecondsFromGMT "for that date" of the event, you'll find people crying their eyes out that their events are showing an hour off. Usually it's best to store the "timezone ID" instead and grab "SecondsFromGMT" for that timezone at runtime for that date, in case the SecondsFromGMT changed (countries often change their DST rules - sucks I know.)