# Date-String -> String-Date disruption?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

So, I was looking another question over here, and cross upon this:

I have an extension for `NSDate`

```
extension NSDate {
    private class var formatter : NSDateFormatter {
        let nsDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        nsDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
        nsDateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        return nsDateFormatter
    }
    //NSString to NSDate
    public convenience init(dateString:String) {
        let dateObj = NSDate.formatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
        self.init(timeInterval: 0, sinceDate: dateObj)
    }

    //NSDate to String
    public func getString() -> String {
       return NSDate.formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

This works just fine:

```
var date = NSDate()                       //"Feb 2, 2016, 12:36 PM"
var string = date.getString()             //"2016-02-02 12:36:11 -0500"

let copyDate = NSDate(dateString: string) //"Feb 2, 2016, 12:36 PM"
copyDate.getString()                      //"2016-02-02 12:36:11 -0500"
```

> **But** if I use, for example:

**"EEE, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz"** as the dateFormat:

```
var date = NSDate()                       //"Feb 2, 2016, 12:58 PM"
var string = date.getString()             //"Tue, 2 Feb 2016 12:58:48 GMT-5"

let copyDate = NSDate(dateString: string) //"Dec 22, 2015, 12:58 PM"
copyDate.getString()                      //"Tue, 22 Dec 2015 12:58:48 GMT-5"
```

**Why is this happening?**

**It shouldn't be working equal to the previous case?**

**Why I have now several days and even a month of time disruption?**

Comment: There's no difference, I already tried that.

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm on my iMac, with a playground open just for this, believe me, I already tried that.

Comment: YYYY in uppercase letters is (in most cases) *not* what you want, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter.

Comment: The problem starts in this line `let dateObj = NSDate.formatter.dateFromString(dateString)!`

Comment: @HugoAlonso http://stackoverflow.com/a/32023076/2303865

Comment: by the way, @MartinR even if using 'y' is the correct way to do it. Why it fails? The NSDateFormatter is the same for both, it shouldn't be returning the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [capital Y for year instead of y](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

> Year (in "Week of Year" based calendars). This year designation is used in ISO year-week calendar as defined by ISO 8601, but can be used in non-Gregorian based calendar systems where week date processing is desired. May not always be the same value as calendar year.

Change the format to `"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"`

You can read more about ISO week date here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. This happens only with years?

Comment: No there are other formatting options in the date format link I provided. For example, `D` is day of the year instead of day of the month.

Comment: by the way, even if this is the correct way to do it. Why it fails? The NSDateFormatter is the same for both, it shouldn't be returning the same data?

Comment: The format doesn't match what is expected. ISO week dates are a whole other beast that I'm not an expert in. But to see consistent results use the expected format: `"YYYY'W'wwe"`.