# Preventing Date from being localized

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have the following string:

```
let dateString = "2018-04-18T04:54:00-04:00"
```

I initialize a `Date` via the `ISO8601DateForamtter` by doing the following:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

If I print the date, I get the following:

```
Apr 18, 2018 at 1:54am
```

The formatter is automatically converting the time into my local time. How can I prevent accounting for my time zone? For example, I want the `Date` object to show the following instead:

```
Apr 18, 2018 at 4:54am
```

Comment: Just use DateFormatter to get the localized string from your date at the desired date format

Comment: How did you print the `date` instance? The date instance basically a time object which doesn't have any timezone information. If you want to specify timezone, you need to do it with the formatter.

Comment: Can you explain the context more? I've dealt with a similar situation where I had to display an airline flight departure time in the local time of the departure city, which may be in a different time zone than the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ISO8601`, `2018-04-18T04:54:00-04:00` means `2018-04-18 04:54:00` in `GMT -4h`. To print the time as it is in the original string, you need to create a date formatter with the specific time zone which is `-4`.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -4 * 60 * 60)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

You will get

```
2018-04-17 04:54:00
```

FYI, I'm adding a link for [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: This helped. I guess the answer is that you can't opt-out of the time zone conversion.

Comment: @LeoDabus Nice catch. Should be 2 ss.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the timezone from your date string and use it to set the timezone from your date formatter:

```
func secondsFromGMT(from string: String) -> Int {
    guard !string.hasSuffix("Z") else { return 0 }
    let timeZone = string.suffix(6)
    let comps = timeZone.components(separatedBy: ":")
    guard let hours = comps.first,
        let minutes = comps.last,
        let hr = Int(hours),
        let min = Int(minutes) else { return 0 }
    return hr * 3600 + min * 60
}
```

---

```
let dateString = "2018-04-18T04:54:00-04:00"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxxx"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
if let dateFromString = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: secondsFromGMT(from: dateString))
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:mma"
    formatter.amSymbol = "am"
    formatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
    print(formatter.string(from: dateFromString))  // Apr 18, 2018 at 4:54am
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `secondFromGMT` function is the right way. According to the standard(ISO8601) the timezone string can be vary. `<time>Z`, `<time>±hh:mm`, `<time>±hhmm`, `<time>±hh`.

Comment: I don't know how your api works this is just an example considering that the timezone would be Z or ±hh:mm. You can adapt the parsing method to your needs

Comment: Thank you guys. This discussion is helping me understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of logging the `Date` directly, have a look at the `string(from:timeZone:formatOptions:)` method on `ISO8601DateFormatter`. With this, you should be able to get a date string for any time zone you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your formatter to the appropriate timezone such as (UTC example below):

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
```

or alternatively specify against GMT:

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Comment: **Apr 18, 2018 at 4:54am**  is the time at -04:00 timezone

Comment: Tried this in playground just now. This didn't affect the date at all.

Comment: you need to set the timezone of your date formatter to -4 hours

Comment: @LeoDabus Is it possible to prevent localizing the time?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "prevent localising the time" You need to interpret the time zone from your string. Are you trying to display the time using the same timezone from your string? you would need to parse the timezone from your string and use it in a custom date formatter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32023076/2303865

Answer (score 0):

The date that you are receiving from your current formatter is technically correct. Setting the date backwards as described in the currently accepted answer is not advised because you are effectively hard-coding an intended time zone. As soon as your device enters another time zone (or if a user downloads your app outside of the current time zone), your information will be incorrect.

If you are trying to *display* this time in the UTC time zone, you need to use another formatter to correctly format the output in the target time zone.

```
let utcFormatter = DateFormatter()
utcFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
// Perform any other transformations you'd like
let output = utcFormatter.string(from: date)
```

---

But *why* is your original date correct?

The `Date` API is incredibly robust and doing a lot of things under-the-hood, but is effectively implemented using a simple `Double`. The automaic time-zone information that it's displaying to you is an abstraction to make it easier to reason about. A date technically has no knowledge of what time zone it's in – but converting it to a string implicitly applies an inferred date formatter on the date and returns information it thinks will be most useful to you.

If you're doing manipulations on a date, you're likely using the `Calendar` API. You typically get a new instance from using `Calendar.current`, which will create a new calendar with your current time zone information. You can change the represented time zone of the calendar like this:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

This will give you relative dates that will work in any time zone without modifying the base `Date` object that you're working with.